# Change selected instance in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, usability, ssms-2012

In SSMS, each tab is related to an instance and a DB.

There's a top left drop down where we can change the selected DB for current tab. But, if SSMS is connected to multiple instances, I don't see a way to change the selected instance of a tab. I need to copy the text, close the tab, select the correct instance, open a new tab, and past the text back.

Is there a smarter way to do this change?

Comment: Not sure if this is dependent upon a certain edition of SSMS, but you can right-click in the background of your query window and select `Connection -> Change Connection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this by right clicking.  Choose *Connection* > *Change Connection* from the context menu.

[image]

It's possible to add this button to the menu bar (but in SSMS 2016 I can't get it to work).  In other versions click the down arrow at the end of the menu bar.  From *Add or Remove Buttons* you can customise the available options.

You can also [customise the colour of the status line](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1871/customizing-the-status-bar-for-each-sql-server-ssms-connection/), based on which server you are connected to.  Handy if you often jump between servers and then get confused!  ;P

Comment: is there a way to achieve this using sql, like `Instance_Name.DB_Name.Schema_Name.Table_Name`?

Comment: You can query the instance name and current db.  But the SQL language doesn't include commands that edit connections.